# Inner function cannot access scope of outer function gives cannot read property toString() of undefined error

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I'm not able to access the `this.curr_prod_data` array instantiated in the conditional block in the outer function from the inner function. I'm passing a flag variable to the outer function to test if object is already instantiated.

If it is already instantiated (flag =1), I just want to call a method updateCurrentQuote on the already created object. In order to test the scope, I created a test variable 'a' which I have assigned in the `if` block. I am able to access it in the inner function. Here is my code:

```
function addProdData(p_id, tick_sym , ind, curr_price, length, _flag) {
    this.a;
    this.flag = _flag;
    this.curr_prod_data = new Array(length);

    if(!this.flag) {
        this.curr_prod_data[ind] = new ProductMarketData(p_id, tick_sym, ind, null, null, null);
        console.log("object: "+ this.curr_prod_data[ind].toString()); //Prints properties of class object
        this.curr_prod_data[ind].updateCurrentQuote(curr_price);  //No error
        this.a = "hi";
    } 
    else {
        updateold(curr_price, ind);
    }

    function updateold(price, index) {
        console.log("ind "+index);
        console.log("a "+this.a);   //Prints value of a: Hi
        console.log("object: "+ this.curr_prod_data[index].toString()); //Gives cannot read property toString of undefined
        this.curr_prod_data[index].updateCurrentQuote(price);
    }
}
```

This is where I'm calling the function

```
if(js_object[0].hasOwnProperty('tickerSymbol')) {
    for(var j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
        var flag = 0;
        if($("#product_select li").length > 0) {
            $("#product_select li a").each(function() {
                if(($.trim($(this).html())) == js_object[j].tickerSymbol){
                    flag = 1;
                }
            });
        }

        console.log("flag: "+ flag);
        if(!flag) {
            $("#product_select").append("<li id ="+j+"><a>" +    js_object[j].tickerSymbol + "</a></li>");
            $("#product_select li:eq(0) a").css({"background-color": "lightblue", "border-color" : "blue"});
            addProdData(js_object[j].productID, js_object[j].tickerSymbol, j, js_object[j].curr_price, size, flag);
        }
        else {
            console.log("oldj ="+ j);
            addProdData(js_object[j].productID, js_object[j].tickerSymbol, j, js_object[j].curr_price, size, flag);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: How are you invoking `addProdData`? Is it a method on an object, or an event listener, or simply called with `addProdData(...)`?

Comment: simply called using the parameters

Comment: yea you are right, when I change the declaration to this.curr_prod_data = new Array(length); it gives me cannot call method toString() on undefined in the inner function 'updateold'

Comment: Please edit your question and show us more code.

Comment: i have added more code

Comment: The last code part seems to be missing an ending "}".

Comment: I solved it by making curr_prod_data static object for the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the curr_prod_data array a static object to the function. Any idea why I had to do this to make this work??

```
    addProdData.curr_prod_data =[];

    function addProdData(p_id, tick_sym , ind, curr_price, _flag) {
       this.a;
       this.flag = _flag;


      if(!this.flag) {
        addProdData.curr_prod_data[ind] = new ProductMarketData(p_id, tick_sym, ind, null, null, null);
        console.log("object: "+addProdData.curr_prod_data[ind].toString());
        addProdData.curr_prod_data[ind].updateCurrentQuote(curr_price);
        this.a ="hi";
      } else {
          updateold(ind, curr_price);
      }

   function updateold(price, index) {
       console.log("ind "+index);
       console.log("a "+this.a);
       addProdData.curr_prod_data[index].updateCurrentQuote(price);
   }
}
```